# Quarkus - Changing the default session cookie name

Tags: quarkus, undertow

How to change de default session cookie name in Quarkus? The default cookie name is JSESSIONID and the application property "quarkus.http.auth.form.cookie-name" do not seems to work neither the `<cookie-config>` tag in web.xml.

Answer (score 1):

Can you file a bug? This has not been wired up properly, the web.xml parser does not pass the value into Undertow.